# Record a video of a particular div and save as a gif

Tags: javascript, reactjs

Here is the div I want to record:

```
<QrBackground ref={ref}>
    <Circle/>
</QrBackground>
```

In the center of the `QrBackground`, there is a red circle that I want to record for `5 seconds`

What would be the best way to record the circle and save as a 5 second gif?

Answer (score -2):

[`remotion`](https://www.remotion.dev/) is probably what you are looking for

Comment: I'd assume because it's a link-only answer to a third-party plugin.

Comment: I thought that's what op is looking for. But maybe we should close the question instead if expected answers are disliked.

Comment: Some more context re link-only answers: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/8231/are-answers-that-just-contain-links-elsewhere-really-good-answers

Comment: One of the deletion reasons for SO questions is "Seeking recommendations for books, tools, software libraries, and more", because they tend to be opinion-based. (This question is mostly ok on that point, it doesn't specifically ask for a library; it's light on detail but could in theory be meaningfully answerable.) Answers can include links to libraries and frameworks, of course, but if that's _all_ they contain they're going to attract downvotes compared to answers that explain how to do what the question is asking for.  (External links rot, libraries stop being supported, etc)